# Stream audio from Logic Pro X to mobile device

Tags: ios, audio, headphones, android, logic

I am creating an interactive project in which participants explore a room (a real one, not virtually) with their mobile device — iOS or Android — and headphones.

The music in their headphones will change depending on where they are. I'm controlling the music from Logic Pro X from my laptop - I'll have to react fairly quickly.

So, I'd like to stream the live audio output from Logic Pro X to mobile devices. Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

I've got as far as trying to stream Logic audio to VLC Player, both on my Mac, via Soundflower. Didn't work so far — though I changed audio input and output in both applications and system preferences accordingly! — so I'm looking for alternatives.

If all fails, I can just use speakers in the room… but headphones are spookier.

Comment: I've never tried this myself, but Rogue Amoeba do an OTA system - [Airfoil](https://rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/) - which might be worth a look.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thank you! On the landing page it looked like it didn't work for Android, but apparently it does, which is great. I'll give it a try.